# Google does not treat a pseudo-element whose content property value type is '<content-replacement>' as a replaced element rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I cited a problem-related example in the codesandbox, and my description of the problem is also in it.
Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hofstadter-hjnbv?file=/index.html

Comment: I see your content is an svg. I don't claim to at all understand what the intrinsic width will therefore be. Can you put up a working snippet including your svg so we can see more clearly what is going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi,Haworth.I gave an example in codesandbox,Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hofstadter-hjnbv?file=/index.html

Comment: The sizing is consistent across Chrome/Edge, Firefox and IE11 at least on my Windows10 system, so it's not just a Chrome phenomenon. Somehow the pseudo element is not becoming a replaced 'element' in the same way as the box2 div is. Hope someone can explain.

Comment: change the question title by removing special characters and add it to your question description instead of posting simple hyperlink